# Does a continuous, bounded, lattice-valued correspondence have a continuous least upper bound?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, integer-lattices

Suppose $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. 
In addition, assume $Y$ is a bounded, complete lattice with respect to the product order.
Suppose $\Gamma: X \to 2^Y$ is a correspondence from $X$ to subsets of $Y$ such that $\Gamma(x) \subset Y$ is a complete sublattice for all $x \in X$.

If $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is continuous, is $\bar{g}(x) := \sup \Gamma(x)$ also continuous?

Comment: Is the topology on $Y$ supposed to be related to its lattice structure?  What topology are you putting on $2^Y$?

Comment: @EricWofsey I think for my purposes it is ok to just assume $X$ and $Y$ take values in Euclidean space. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: But what does it mean for $\Gamma$ to be continuous?  What is the topology on $2^Y$?

Comment: @EricWofsey $\Gamma$ is continuous if it is both upper hemi continuous and lower hemi continuous, and these concepts are defined only by the topologies on $X$ and $Y$, no?